# How can I smooth and seal a degraded interior door?

Tags: doors, woodworking

I have an old hollow-core door and it's quite old and has lost its finish. It's begun splitting at the grains, on the stiles and rails, and my kids keep getting splinters fondling the door as they shouldn't.

What can I do to seal the door and its burst out ends to prevent getting splinters from handling it? I fear painting it would draw more attention to these burst out ends whereas the door on appearance doesn't look so old and battered.

[image]

Comment: A hollow core door might just be easier to replace.  Repair will need sanding, stain and sealer.  Those door finishes are usually thin, so careful sanding.

Comment: Answers depend on details. Please provide a more thorough description or photos. I'm not sure what "burst out ends" are.

Comment: Depending on which side of the door is damaged (and we're just guessing, without pics), you could glue on a new sheet of laminate without effecting the door's ability to close against the stops. However, I'm going to jump on the "simpler, easier, cheaper in the long-run to replace it" bandwagon...

Comment: @manassehkatz-Moving2Codidact picture added

Comment: @keshlam that's not even the question, it's hollow-core 100%. The panel is fine strangely, but the stiles and rails are heavily abused as the post mentions.

Comment: Ah. I did misread.

Comment: @crip659 I see prehung interior hollow core wood doors start at 200-300 USD at box stores. Counting DIY time for demoing the old door, shimming up and fastening down the new door, and trimming it out...  I can't believe it's less time/money than doing a passable (not perfect) repair.

Comment: If it is only the real wood at the edges and not the panel/faces, then repair is more doable.  The edges can take more sanding(usually an inch thick) to get them smooth.  It is usually the faces that get the almost abuse, not the edges unless rubbing on the frame.

Comment: How particular are you aesthetically?  A simple strip of packing tape along the edge will prevent splinters.

Comment: That picture is, wow... can you please get us something that's in focus and gives us an idea of what we're really looking at? Close up is good, but so is over view and context setting, and focused is even better.

Comment: That doesn't look like hollow-core door to me. Don't I see a diagonal Z-rail?